# How to change default new file template Presentation on WPS Office Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: default, presentation, wps-office, templates

I tried to google about how to change the WPS Office Presentation default new file template but did not find any solution.

I did not like the Presentation's new file template because the default font was Arial and I don't install it in Ubuntu. Also I don't like the drop shadow effect.

[image]

I figured this out myself, and I hope people out there can get answer from my answer post below. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and downloaded WPS 2019 version 11.1.0.10161 from the website https://linux.wps.com/

If you are using ubuntu and installing from the website's deb file, then most probably the installation location and settings are same as mine, so you can try to follow this.

1. Edit your desired Presentation template. And this means we want to edit from the Slide Master. In the ribbon, open `Design > Edit Slide Master` then edit all of the fonts or background if you like. Then after you finish, go to the ribbon `Slide Master`, then click Close.
2. Save this file as **newfile_linux.pptx** on your `/home/Documents` folder
3. Find the default new file template for WPS Presentation. Mine is located at here, so find it in your file browser.

> /opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/mui/en_US/templates/Wpp Default Object/prometheus/newfile_linux.pptx

4. We want to replace the file on point 3 with the file we created on point 2. But that default file is read-only, so we need to remove this file first then replace it with the one we created. You may want to copy the original default template for a backup. To remove it, type this in Terminal (ctrl + alt + T)

> sudo rm -r "/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/mui/en_US/templates/Wpp
> Default Object/prometheus/newfile_linux.pptx"

Then it will ask your password, just type it it's invisible. Then press enter.

5. Now move your own created file on point 2 to the WPS default new file location. Type this in Terminal

> sudo mv "/home/brian/Documents/newfile_linux.pptx"
> "/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/mui/en_US/templates/Wpp Default
> Object/prometheus/newfile_linux.pptx"

That's it! I hope this helps you. Please give a vote button if it does.